# linking private documents in public directory

Tags: unix, symbolic-link

On an OS X server, I have some documents in /Users/me/Documents/here/

Permissions to /Users/me/Documents is set to `drwxrwxr--`.

Permissions to /Users/me/Documents/here is set to `drwxrwxr-x`.

I want to allow other users to access only the contents of here/ within Documents (so I don't have to copy the whole thing to my Public directory). For this I have tried

```
cd /Users/me/Public
ln -s /Users/me/Documents/here here
```

I can of course access here/ through my Public directory, but others users cannot. Is there a way to enable this while keeping everything else in /Users/me/Documents private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change permission on `/Users/me/Documents` to `drwxrwx--x`.
Without the execute permission on a directory, you can not descend through it.
But with read permission, you can list the files.

By using `chmod 771 /Users/me/Documents`, you'll let them descend through to `here`, but not be able to see the contents.